# Check if string is valid EL expression (Java)

Tags: java, regex, el

I need to check if input string is a valid EL expression or not, so that I can set it's actual value. It can be done by either regex or some existing java library/code.

Input and Output could be like:

```
"${prop.key}" ==> true
"${prop.method()}" ==> true
"#{prop.key}" ==> true
"prop.key" ==> false
"${prop key}" ==> false
"{prop.key}" ==> false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate and/or evaluate the expression, use an EL parser, e.g. [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/).